# Generating function question about arranging n objects with limitations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Generating functions question: There are n objects - rings, earring and bracelets. How many ways are there to arrange these objects, as the amount of earring is even and there are at most 4 bracelets.

[This is a question we must solve with generating functions].

Here's what I started:

There are $n$ objects, at most 4 bracelets. There are $2k$ bracelets when $2k \leq n$. So there are $n-2k-4$ rings at most.

I defined the following generating function: $$A(x)=(x^0+x^1+...+x^{n-2k-4})(x^0+x^2+...+x^{2k})(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)={1-x^{n-2k-3}\over 1-x}\cdot {1-x^{2k+1}\over 1-x^2}\cdot {1-x^5 \over 1-x}$$

So I tried simplfying it... and.... well it didn't go well.

Is there another way to solve this? Is my direction even correct?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: a) You're not counting what you said you wanted to count. You asked for the number of ways to arrange certain objects, but what you're counting is all ways to arrange all sets of objects compatible with the given conditions. (My guess would be that it's the formulation of the question, not the answer, that's at fault.) b) What's the intended interpretation of this generating function? c) $x^0+x^2+\dots+x^{2k}=(1-x^{2k+2})/(1-x^2)$ (with exponent $2k+2$, not $2k+1$).

Comment: Hmmm... so I don't really know how to solve this :s

Comment: Your chances of getting a useful answer are much higher if you interact with comments.

Comment: Sorry. As for a), I don't know how then should I count? With exponential generated function? For b), this is for counting the even number of bracelet, and using the formula for the sum of a finite geometric sequence I got that it's with the exponent of $2k+2$. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t be building $n$ into your generating function: you actually want the coefficient of $x^n$ in the (correct) generating function, which is

$$A(x)=\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}x^{2k}\right)\left(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4\right)\;.$$

The first factor is for rings, of which you may have any number, the second is for earrings, of which you must have an even number, and the last is for bracelets, of which you must have at most $4$. Thus,

$$A(x)=\frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac1{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}=\frac{1-x^5}{(1-x)^3(1+x)}\;.$$

Divide out, expand the remaining rational function into partial fractions, convert to power series, and find the coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: Why can you use the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric sequence if the number of objects is finite? And when do you know if to use the finite formula or the infinite formula?

Comment: @ohad: You want $A(x)$ to be $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$, where $a_n$ is the number of ways of choosing $n$ rings, earrings, and bracelets that satisfy the given conditions. Of course each particular value of $n$ is finite, but you want your generating function to cover all possible values, so that it gives you $a_{1000}$ as well as $a_{10}$ and $a_{1,000,000}$. If you’d been told that you had at most $m$ objects, you’d have had to truncate the first two summations to finite sums: $\sum_{k=0}^mx^k$ for the first, and $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}x^{2k}$ for the second.

Comment: I see. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ohad: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hey Brian, what did I do wrong? $$(1-x^5) \cdot {1 \over (1-x)^2}\cdot {1 \over 1-x^2}=(1-x^5)\cdot \sum_{n=0}^∞ (n+1)x^n \cdot \sum_{n=0}^∞ x^{2n}=(1-x^5)\cdot \sum_{n=0}^∞  (n+1)x^{3n} $$

Which implies: $a_n=({n \over 1}+1)-{n-5 \over 3}-1={5 \over 3}$ which doesn't make much sense....

Comment: @ohad: The multiplication is incorrect: $$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\right)\ne\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nb_nx^n\;.$$ It’s much better to do what I suggested in the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: I see... This is an algebric frustration. I broke it down and found out that for ${A \over 1+x}+{B \over 1-x}+{C \over (1-x)^2}+{D \over (1-x)^3}$ I get that $A={1 \over 4}, B={25 \over 44}, C={6 \over 33}, D=0$. But then it doesn't make sense, because the coefficient of x^n depends whether n is even or odd... BTW - what is the way to multiply two sums?

Comment: @ohad: If I made no mistake, you should have $$x+2+\frac{4x^2+2x-1}{(1-x)^2(1+x)}$$ to expand after you divide out, yielding $$x+2-\frac{15/4}{1-x}+\frac{5/2}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1/4}{1+x}\;.$$ For the product of two series you want the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: I see, thanks. But still, for the sequence ${1/4 \over 1+x}$ the coefficient of x^n depends on whether n is even or odd, is it not?

Comment: @ohad: Yes, it does. But you’d expect the result to depend on the parity of $n$, given the earring restriction.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know an improper fraction has another technique for finding its partial fraction! Thanks again Brian!

Comment: I solved it and got two solutions: if n is even, the coefficient of $x^n$ is 2.5n-1, and if it is odd, it's 2.5n-1.5. Does it seem right?

Comment: @ohad: (1) Yes, if the degree of the numerator is $\ge$ the degree of the denominator, you **must** divide out first. (2) I’ve not actually worked it out in detail. Those are close, and the first may be completely correct, but the second doesn’t give the correct result for $n=1$: there are actually $2$ possibilities in that case, not $1$. This may be the only bug, however.